# Wrap app with dynamic libraries into one large static app

Tags: linux, gentoo

I have an old program that kind of depends on older dynamic libraries. They tend to get upgraded easily with distro's updates. I figured that there would be a script with using `ldd` that would gather the libs needed and create one bigger, statically linked application that wouldn't break so easily. If I could do this, a lot of older KDE libraries could be removed from my system and easen my life. Thanks!

My distribution of choice is gentoo, but I'm looking for a general solution that doesn't depend on rebuilding anything. If it runs with libs on their path, I'm sure it can be made run with libs somewhere else!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about anything that statically links the old libraries, and I don't see how it would help.  They'd still be on your system, just not as independent files (you'd have multiple copies instead).

But there is a tool, `revdep-rebuild`, that uses `ldd` to find applications needed old dynamic libraries and rebuilds them to use the newest shared library files.  Which also allows you to delete the old ones.

You're not talking about some closed-source (horror!) binary-only (hysteria!) application needing old libraries, are you?

Comment: Heh, no. I'm not. I don't know how revdep-rebuild fits in the picture but I want to keep this question as general as possible. But at the moment revdep-rebuild hasn't solved my issue completely.